# Firefox back button VS IE and Chrome back buttons

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, browser-cache

When I click on the back button of Firefox, the page that is loaded is the cached page. However, when I click on the back button of IE and Chrome, the loaded page will be 'refreshed' (in other words, the page is reloaded from the net).

How can I make IE and Chrome load the cached version of the page similar to Firefox?

Thanks.

Comment: Read this (http://madhatted.com/2013/6/16/you-do-not-understand-browser-history) and this (http://forums.asp.net/t/1840836.aspx?+Different+behaviors+when+pressing+Back+Button+of+Browsers+IE+Chrome+Opera+) articles to understand the nature of the problem.