# Chrome Vs Firefox Back Caching

Tags: google-chrome, browser, safari, browser-cache, back

I have a drupal site with a view that links to detail pages.  The view has paging. Here is the issue:

- In FireFox, when you go from page 8 of the view to a detail page,
  then click the back button, you end up at **page 8** of the view.  (good)
- In Chrome, when you go from page 8 of the view to a detail page, then
  click the back button, you end up at **page 1** of the view. (bad)

I was under the impression that chrome and firefox handled back caching in the same way.  Is this not true?  Is there anything I can do to fix it, i.e., so that in either case you end up at page 8 of the view after clicking the back button?

You can see what I'm talking about at http://www.instepp.umn.edu/publications

Thanks!

Laurie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Digging around a bit more, I found the same question at: [Firefox back button VS IE and Chrome back buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421960/firefox-back-button-vs-ie-and-chrome-back-buttons)

It was answered by the blog post at: http://madhatted.com/2013/6/16/you-do-not-understand-browser-history

In short, the back button on Chrome & Firefox behave differently; nothing I can do about it if my desired behavior is for the back button to return the DOM from cache. If I want the back button to return a refreshed version of the prior page, I have options as detailed in the blog post.

Comment: Comment by [Kyle Bai](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6070885/kyle-bai) The blog post link is changed, I found this. http://madhatted.com/2013/06/16/you-do-not-understand-browser-history. Moved from [non answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40916061/5292302)