# Keep Javascript changes when going back and forward in browser

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser, back-button

I have the following shorted code to easier demonstrate my problem:

```
<script>
function change() {
    document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = "Done!";
}
</script>

<div id="change" onclick="change();">Change me!</div>
```

Let's say the files name is `test.html`.

When clicking on `Change me!` the string will get changed to `Done!`.

Safari, Firefox: When clicking on the browser back button and then the browser forward button to go back to my `test.html`, it's showing `Done!`. This is what I expect!

Doing the same with other browsers (Chrome, Vivaldi, Min, Opera), I'm getting `Change me!` instead of `Done!`.

Safari and Firefox seem to keep the Javascript changes while other browsers load the page without the Javascript changes, when using back and forward buttons.

Is there a way to reach the same behavior for other browser as it's working in Safari and Firefox?

Comment: Why do you want to persist changes, if you trying to manage state of the page or an app try some different and robust approach

Comment: Similar to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837195/chrome-vs-firefox-back-caching

Comment: Try to explain why you need this feature on your code. Maybe you need a single page application? We don't know, try to share your needs

Comment: @AmbrishPathak I have an iOS app that uses a WebView to display the content. There's also a button to add the actual page to the favorites. When clicking on this button it changes to `Is in your favorites`. When a user goes back and the forward to this page again he'll think it's not in his favorites because it's saying `Is NOT in your favorites` now.

Comment: This doesn't seem like the right approach to solve this problem. What happens when the user exits your App and then returns later to a "favorite" page - in that case, FF or Chrome - your page will say `Is NOT in your favorites` , right?

Comment: @Mortz In that case, the page will be refreshed/loaded from server with the right message, because the state is stored in my database and PHP will set the right message (`display:none;` the one message and `display:block;` the other message).

Comment: You can look at using `Window.sessionStorage` or `Window.localStorage` of your browser to store and retrieve the state for the cases where back button/forward buttons are used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at using `Window.sessionStorage` or `Window.localStorage` of your browser to store and retrieve the state for the cases where back button/forward buttons are used

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
setHTML();
})

function setHTML() {
document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = window.sessionStorage.getItem("state")||"NOT IN FAVORITES";
}

function addToFavorites() {
window.sessionStorage.setItem("state", "Done");
document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = window.sessionStorage.getItem("state");

}
</script>

<div id="change" onclick="addToFavorites();">Change me!</div>
```

Comment: You need to change `onclick="change();"` to `onclick="addToFavorites();"`. Made the edit in the answer.

Comment: Your code is working now but it's still the same issue when going back and forward.

Comment: Seems to be working for me - you can try to run `window.sessionStorage.getItem("state")` in the console before and after clicking to see if it is being stored. Also, you can probably put in a `console.log` in the `load` event listener to see if the re-load is being registered on clicking back and forward buttons.

Comment: Can you please check if it's working with the code in your answer? You and I changed it several times and I'm not sure if it's the code that is working for you. Maybe you have an older version?!

Comment: There was a missing `)` in the `window.addEventListener`. Have updated - should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.preventDefault()

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                $("#test").hide();
                **event.preventDefault();** //add this line into your js.
            });
        });
    </script>

<div>
            <h2>This is a heading</h2>
            <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
            <p id="test">This is another paragraph.</p>
            <button>Click me</button>
        </div>
```